# Proof on not subset of one and other?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $A = \{ 2^n -1 |$ n is a prime integer } and let $B$ be the set of all prime integers. Show that $A \not\subset B$ and $B \not\subset A$.

Comment: To show that $A\not\subset B$ you should find an example of an element that is in $A$ but is not in $B$.  The other direction is proven in the same way.  So... can you find an example of $2^n-1$ which is not prime despite $n$ being prime?  Can you find an example of a prime number which cannot be written as $2^n-1$ with $n$ prime?

Comment: A useful search term here is [mersenne primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that $B\not\subset A$ a counter example is $5$ since $5\in B$ but $5\not\in A$.

To show that $A\not\subset B$ a counter example is $2^{11}-1$ since $2^{11}-1\in A$ but $2^{11}-1\not\in B$ since we have $2^{11}-1=23\times89$.

Comment: @pilgrim A typo: $2^{11}-1=23\times \mathbf{89}$.

Comment: I have corrected the set inclusions and the typo.